# What's the density of $(0, Z)$ when $Z \sim U([0,1])$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $Z \sim U([0,1])$ be a uniform distribution.

I'm asked, if you define $\mathbb{P}$ to be the distribution of $(0,Z) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ what is its density function?

I'm not sure I understand exactly what the definition of $(0,Z)$ says. Is it supposed to be a density $[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]^2$, $(x,y) \mapsto (0,1)$?

Can you help clarify what this distribution represents, and what its density is?

Taken from: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf page 4

Comment: @StubbornAtom I corrected - they do not write it is an r.v. But what they do, see correction, isn't more indicative I think.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I overlooked that it can be seen as a random vector indeed as the answer below says.

Comment: @d.k.o. indeed, I guess we should consider this distribution over $[0,1]^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling a vector of random variables (random vector) it is natural to consider not just the their respective marginals but also the joint. Without more context, it seems reasonable to opt for the following convention:

The first of $(X, Z)$ is a degenerate distribution $X = c=\text{constant}$, a single point mass, thus necessarily $Z$ is independent to $X$. Namely, the joint "density" is

$$f_{X,Z}(x,z)=\delta(x-c) \cdot \frac1{b-a}\mathbb{I}_{a \le z \le b} \qquad \text{, with } c = 0,\, b=1,\, a=0,$$

where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function and $\mathbb{I}_{\text{blah}}$ is the indicator function.

Now, in the paper it is stated that $(0, Z)$ is "a zero on the $x$-axis and the random variable $Z$ on the $y$-axis). Seems pretty clear to me that the two components are meant to be independent. After all, the intro to **Example** $\pmb 1$ is "The following example illustrates how apparently simple sequences ... (converge under ... but do not converge...)"

Also, a few lines after listing the several distances, the authors say "Although this simple example features distribution**S** with *disjoint supports*..." , which implies that they view this random vector as merely concatenating two independent distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited my question with the article this is from. Does that help any further?